# How can I calculate correlation coefficient from regression cofficient?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

If we have one independent variable, then the given regression coefficient $\beta$ = Pearson's $r$. If we have multiple independent variables, how can calculate Pearson's $r$ for each variable if only $\beta$ values are given for each independent variable? (Assume I have T1, T2, T3 independent variables and I have $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $\beta_3$, i.e path coefficients or regression coefficients given. So, how can I calculate $r$ value for each independent variable?

Comment: You can't deduce correlation from slope. Also, could you edit the first sentence to make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, it's done. Like its not slope but its the regression coefficient ß.

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 3):

> If we have one independent variable, then the given regression coefficient $\beta$ = Pearson's $r$.

This is not correct. A simple argument is that regression coefficients are not bounded between [-1,1] (e.g. $\beta=15$ is nothing extraordinary) while the correlation coefficient $r$ is.

> If we have multiple independent variables, how can calculate Pearson's $r$ for each variable if only $\beta$ values are given for each independent variable.

You cannot. $\beta$s do not imply $r$s, i.e. for a fixed set of $\beta$s you may have different $r$s.

Comment: With a single IV, the standardised regression coefficient is equal to the correlation coefficient, so the OP was not entirely wrong on this point.

Comment: @TimBainbridge, you are welcome to provide such an answer.

Comment: I realised a previous comment of mine was a little silly, so I've deleted it. I think this is a sufficient and correct answer. Sorry!

Comment: @TimBainbridge, no worries! I did not think it was all that silly, and you are indeed welcome to post a better answer.